# Hilt Testing - Replace internal Hilt-Module in separate Android multi-module app

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, dagger-hilt

I have an Android app where the codebase is split into 2 different modules: **App** and **Domain**

**Goal**: I am attempting to use the Hilt provided testing functionality to replace a **Domain internal** dependency when creating **App** tests.

In **Domain**, I have an internal interface with an internal implementation, like below:

```
internal interface Database {
    fun add(value: String)
}

internal class DatabaseImpl @Inject constructor() : Database {
    override fun add(value: String) { ... }
}
```

The above guarantees that the Database can ***only be used inside Domain*** and cannot be accessed from elsewhere.

In **Domain** I have another interface (which is not internal), for use in **App**, with an internal implementation, like below:

```
interface LoginService {
    fun userLogin(username: String, password: String)
}

internal class LoginServiceImpl @Inject constructor(database: Database) {
    override fun userLogin(username: String, password: String) {
        // Does something with the Database in here
    }
}
```

In **Domain** I use Hilt to provide dependencies to **App**, like below:

```
@Module(includes = [InternalDomainModule::class]) // <- Important. Allows Hilt access to the dependencies provided by InternalDomainModule.
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class DomainModule {
   ...
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
internal class InternalDomainModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase() : Database = DatabaseImpl()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLoginService(database: Database) : LoginService = LoginServiceImpl(database)
}
```

This all works perfectly in isolating my implementations and only exposes a single interface outside of **Domain**.

***However***, when I need to provide fake implementations inside **App** using the [Hilt guidelines](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#replace-binding), I am unable to replace the `LoginService` as I do not have access to `InternalDomainModule` (because it is internal to Domain only) and replacing `DomainModule` does not replace `LoginService` (as it is provided in another Hilt module, namely `InternalDomainModule`), like below:

```
@Module
@TestInstallIn(
    components = [SingletonComponent::class],
    replaces = [DomainModule::class] // [InternalDomainModule::class] is impossible as inaccessible in **App**
)
class FakeModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFakeLoginService() : LoginService = FakeLoginServiceImpl() <- Something fake
}
```

The above leads to **only** DomainModule being replaced, not InternalDomainModule, which leads to LoginService being provided twice, which makes Hilt unhappy.

Making things not internal to **Domain** fixes the issue, but defeats the purpose of having a multi-module Android app with clear separations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

I would make the internal `LoginService` in some way different for Dagger than the public one. For example, add a qualifier to it:

```
@Module(includes = [InternalDomainModule::class])
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class DomainModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLoginService(
        @Named("Internal") internalLoginService: LoginService
    ) : LoginService = internalLoginService
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
internal class InternalDomainModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase() : Database = DatabaseImpl()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("Internal")
    fun provideLoginService(database: Database) : LoginService = LoginServiceImpl(database)
}
```

This way, it won't be duplicated in tests.

**Solution 2:**

Even better, you could implement a `LoginServiceFactory`:

```
interface LoginServiceFactory {
    fun create(): LoginService
}

internal class LoginServiceFactoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val database: Database
) : LoginServiceFactory {
    override fun create(): LoginService =
        LoginServiceImpl(database)
}
```

Then your modules would look like this:

```
@Module(includes = [InternalDomainModule::class])
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class DomainModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLoginService(loginServiceFactory: LoginServiceFactory) : LoginService =
        loginServiceFactory.create()
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
internal class InternalDomainModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase() : Database = DatabaseImpl()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLoginServiceFactory(database: Database) : LoginServiceFactory =
        LoginServiceFactoryImpl(database)
}
```

Comment: Solution 1 is nice and it works!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is to make the inner module `public`, but make all its functions `internal` instead. This way the module can be replaced in tests:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class InternalDomainModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideDatabase() : Database = DatabaseImpl()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideLoginService(database: Database) : LoginService = LoginServiceImpl(database)
}
```